# restructuring a file with one column as identifier

Tags: bash

I am still new in bash scripting and would need some assistance - I have a rather straightforward istuation I believe:

I want to restructure one file, using one of the columns as identifier to a single list, so:

```
chr1    876498  876499  rs4372192  0  +  chr1  860260  879955  SAMD11

chr1    879675  879676  rs6605067  0  +  chr1  860260  879955  SAMD11

chr1    879675  879676  rs6605067  0  +  chr1  879584  894689  NOC2L

chr1    879686  879687  rs2839     0  +  chr1  860260  879955  SAMD11

chr1    879686  879687  rs2839     0  +  chr1  879584  894689  NOC2L

chr1    880237  880238  rs3748592  0  +  chr1  879584  894689  NOC2L
```

I want the last column (gene) as identifier for rs (4th column), to get something like:

```
SAMD11 rs4372192 rs6605067       

NOC2L rs6605067 rs3748592
```

etc...

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, for ever 10th column Gene, list all the rsIdentifiers that match?

Comment: Are you insistent that it be done in bash only? Other technologies (perl one-liner, maybe awk) could handle it more easily.

Comment: Exactly - list rs that match each gene, in that format

Comment: Yes, I know I could do it with other technologies, but I haven't started in perl yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '!($NF in a){a[$NF]=$4; next} {a[$NF]=a[$NF] " " $4}
      END {for (i in a) print i " " a[i]}' file
SAMD11 rs4372192 rs6605067 rs2839
NOC2L rs6605067 rs2839 rs3748592
```

OR to get them in new lines:

```
awk '!($NF in a){a[$NF]=$4; next} {a[$NF]=a[$NF] "\n" $4}
      END {for (i in a) print i "\n" a[i]}' file

SAMD11
rs4372192
rs6605067
rs2839
NOC2L
rs6605067
rs2839
rs3748592
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in `awk` should work - it's not specifically a `bash`-only solution, though:

```
awk '{tags[$10]=tags[$10] " " $4}END{for (t in tags) printf "%s%s\n",t,tags[t]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
perl -lane 'push @{$x{$F[-1]}},$F[3]}END{$,=" ";print$_,@{$x{$_}}for keys%x'
```

Given the sample input, it outputs

```
NOC2L rs6605067 rs2839 rs3748592
SAMD11 rs4372192 rs6605067 rs2839
```

A bit more readable

```
perl -lane '
        push @{$x{$F[-1]}}, $F[3]
    } END {
        $, = " ";
        print $_, @{$x{$_}} for keys %x
'
```